# XCode 8.3.2 Storyboard UI elements won't appear in simulator

Tags: ios, swift

disclaimer: I've found a number of these questions but none of them helped.

Just like the title says, the storyboard UI elements for my CarDetailViewController won't appear in the simulator, but they do in other view controllers in the project.

[vc in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1YXN.png)

[overall project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX6Ut.png)

code:

```
import UIKit
import EventKit
import CoreData


class CarDetailViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet weak var carLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func photoFromLibrary(_ sender: UIButton) {
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self
    self.view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Landing.png"))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@nonobjc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: AnyObject])
{
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
    myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
    myImageView.image = chosenImage as? UIImage //4
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //5
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: remove this line     self.view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Landing.png"))

Comment: Can you please elaborate What do you mean by won't appear in the simulator?

Comment: kkrocks that bit sets the background color of the app and when removed the screen is just black.

Comment: ipeter -- yes, so all of the ui elements in other pages appear, but when I navigate to this particular page no UI elements are on the page. Just a blank screen with the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Remove this Line :**

```
self.view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Landing.png"))
```

**You need to set background image as**

```
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Landing.png")!)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. could this segue be the issue? It comes from a table view.
                                                                                                                           Edit: jesus the formatting. Let me work on that before i post it haha

Comment: edited the question with the code I *think* might be the issue

Comment: did you try to remove my suggested line ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that and when it's removed the screen associated with the problem vc is black. Probably worth noting that the line you suggested I remove is in all of the other pages as well and works with the various UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

you donot assign an imageview into a uiview
so instead of

```
self.view = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Landing.png"))
```

You have the following options:

1. You should add a uiimageview into your uiview and assign it that image.
2. you can create a gradient background color with this image.

IMHO use the first approach, as the second might cause resolution issues with different devices

**Edit update:**
Instead of initializing the vc as following

```
let destination = CarDetailViewController() // Your destination
```

try doing the following

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: <Storyboard-name>, bundle: nil)
let inquireViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing:CarDetailViewController.self)) as! CarDetailViewController
```

Comment: Thanks! But even if I remove that line I just have a black screen on the simulator.

Comment: Yes, worth mentioning the line of code you're suggesting I change is also in all of the other view controllers and works fine with the various UI elements. This is the only page that is a problem.

Comment: sometimes restarting the xcode and cleaning the code does the trick. u tried it?

Comment: Yeah I tried it. Still having the same issue. Black screen if I just remove it, only background image if it's there or if I set the a background color with the image. Do you think it could be in the segue code I added to the question (check the bottom of the prompt for the code)

Comment: Hmm. so the storyboard name is the storyboard ID for the sending viewcontroller, right? if so this just crashes it when I attempt to navigate to the vc. https://pastebin.com/yA880qqb

Comment: did u assign the carDetailVC a storyboard id in the storyboard? it is usually under the identity inspector section when u select the VC in storyboard, right below where u link it to the class